расшифровка ответа сервера TomCat в логах
При некоторых запросах в логе пишется ответ HTTP/1.1" 500 1081 или HTTP/1.1" 500 2054.
Что значат цифры после кода ответа 500? Чаще всего они одинаковые, в зависимости от типа запроса. Где найти расшифровку 1081 или 2054?

Что-то тоже нигде ничего такого не могу найти. Не может это сам сервис возвращать, который на нём висит? Какая-то внутренняя ошибка сервиса.
